# Does the unconditional distribution of $y_i$ only depend on the distribution of the errors?

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, error, assumptions

In linear regression, does the unconditional distribution of $y_i$ only depend on the distribution of the errors?

For example, is it not the case that if

$$y_i = \beta_0 +\beta_1 x_i + u_i $$

and

$$u \sim N(0, \sigma^2) $$

then

$$y \sim N(\beta_0 +\beta_1 x, \sigma^2) $$

because the the $\beta$s are constant values and the $x$s are fixed in repeated samples?

The reason I ask is that, in Economics, people are always trying to take the natural logarithm of income and earnings to make them look normal (I am aware that there are other properties of the natural logarithm that people like using with respect to these measures but the normal one is one I see repeated an awful lot).

I always thought it was the *conditional* distribution of $y$ we needed to worry about, but perhaps I am wrong. To compound my confusion, Wooldrige has the following quote in his undergraduate textbook:

> Recall that Assumption MLR.6 is equivalent to saying that the distribution of $y$ given $x_1, x_2, ..., x_k$ is normal. Because $y$ is observed and $u$ is not, in a particular application, it is much easier to think about whether the distribution of $y$ is likely to be normal.

Here he seems to be using the unconditional and conditional distribution of $y$ interchangeably! So which is the more important?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate. You should be able to find an answer in an earlier thread.

Comment: This question appears to be ambiguous.  In your example, what is the relationship between "$x_i$" and "$x$"? Are you thinking of the $x_i$ as random variables or fixed values?

Comment: If conditional distribution $y|x$ is heavily skewed, then regression model would still work better with a transformation $g_x(y)|x$ where I made the transformation look like it depends on $x$. If for every $x$ the desired conditional transformation is a log, then you can just treat that as a desired marginal transformation as well.